# Difference between file-nr and /proc/<pid>/fd/*

Tags: c, linux

I want to know how many file descriptor are in use within my system. But I have a signifiant difference between :

> ls /proc/[0-9][0-9]*/fd/* | wc -l
>
> 543

and

> cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
>
> 1887

[This link](https://serverfault.com/questions/485262/number-of-file-descriptors-different-between-proc-sys-fs-file-nr-and-proc-pi) propose an explication but I Don't understand why we need to count file descriptor for each thread of a process since file descriptor are shared between thread…

Anybody can help me to understand ?

Comment: You're correct, that answer must be wrong.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/601703/197504 This is the correct answer.